# Which database is the best for ICAP Squid transparent proxy?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, squid, transparentproxy, icap

I am not sure which database is the best for transparent proxy server, I am using Squid ICAP (client) and Greasyspoon ICAP server. It is running on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I am planning to use this db in order to filter URLs and to connect it with my antimalware sandboxed javascript engine which will be module connected to Squid. I suppose MySQL or NoSQL(Mongodb,Cassandra) databases are the favourites for my solution. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your use-case appears so trivial that any of the proposed solutions would work. But maybe it only appears so trivial because you are not saying anything about the hidden complexities which one database could handle better than another. Anyway, we don't do product recommendations because they are too discussion-oriented. Stackoverflow only deals with factual questions and doesn't do opinion-polling.

Comment: Well a need to connect my ICAP server with db so that it could be able to achieve fastest webrequests processing results.Once URL is scanned it should be stored inside db and next time when requested if webpage is not updated, safe(scanned) webpage from db would be returned to user.

Comment: So you intend to store HTML in the database as big blobs of data? Do you want to check if a website was updated by comparing it to what is stored in the database?

Comment: Yes I want to compare the content and then if it is the same I would return html from my db and cache. If URL content is changed, than I would scan URL first and then if site is clean let the content to user and save it to db.